# QGIS Server: SLD and SLD_BODY parameters in GetMap request

Tags: qgis, wms, sld, server, getmap

Does Qgis server support SLD and SLD_BODY parameters in GetMap request?

I'm trying to give a valid .sld to qgis server but it returns empty image in response.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your QGIS version. If you use QGIS server 3 then the SLD support was dropped due to another change https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19795.

> With the suppression of the class QgsHttpTransaction, the support of
>   SLD parameter has been removed.

The support is coming back with this pull request https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/7859.

Comment: Thank you for so quick answer! From a topic you wrote I understand that SLD_BODY parameter still works. So, I will temporally use it!

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem with QGIS Server 3.28.13 even if the support of SLD parameter seems to have been fixed